# Automatically Add Email Attachments to Inbox In Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

First off, I apologize for not having much to start with. I'm clueless when it comes to VB and Outlook. I have a pretty strong background in Java/Python, though, if that helps make explaining things easier.

Basically, I have emails autoforwarded from another outlook account via a "forward this email as an attachment" rule. I use the "as an attachment" part to keep the original "To" and "Cc" fields intact for reply-all situations.

What I would like to do is, when I receive this email with no body that has an attachment with the actual email I care about in it, move (copy) the attached email to my inbox and delete the original "container email."

I found a [post about moving attachments to a folder](http://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook), and the code makes sense, but I can't find anything about dealing with email folders.

Is there any way to do this with VB/Rules?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the MailItem.Move method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Of course, you will need to build in sufficient logic per your requirement:

> What I would like to do is, when I receive this email with no body that has an attachment with the actual email I care about in it, move (copy) the attached email to my inbox and delete the original "container email."

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible to use an attachement as mail-item. Therefore you will have to save it locally, and then open it as mail-item. But this still does not allow you to move the attached mail-item back into outlook. Would be great if someone has an solution for this!